# Spring Java Excel file download garbled but emails just fine

Tags: java

So, I have a perplexing problem.  I'm creating an excel file with org.apache.poi 3.10.

I can email the excelfile:

```
MimeMessagePreparator mimeprep = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        @Override
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("somewhere@someplace", "Subject line"));
            mimeMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("myplace@myaddress.com", "My Name"));
            mimeMessage.setSubject("Spreadsheet");

            MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messagePart.setText("Anarchy export attached.");

            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachmentPart.setFileName(excelFile.getName());
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(excelFile.getAbsoluteFile())));

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

            mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
        }
    };

    try {
        this.mailSender.send(mimeprep);

    } catch (MailException e) {
        logger.error("Could not send mail", e);
        throw new MailParseException(e);
    }
```

When I do that, the file opens up beautifully.  But I'm also sending the file to the user as a download:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/exportSpreadsheet", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
@ResponseBody
public void exportSpreadsheet(HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Film> allFilms = filmRepository.findAll();

    File excelFile = this.excelHelper.excelOfFilms(allFilms);
    this.mailHelper.emailFile(excelFile);

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"spreadsheet.xls\"");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error exporting spreadsheet in excel", e);
    }
}
```

And when I do that, the file opens up all garbled.  I can't figure out why that's the case!!  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you remove `response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")`?

Comment: Same thing.  No change.  :(

Comment: Just a long shot, try response.getOutputStream().close() After flushBuffer